# Derive equation for theoretical pressure rise in tunnel from jet fan?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure, momentum

This is the rough setup i'm referring to [image]

I believe this is the final equation for the maximum theoretical achievable pressure rise in the tunnel due to a running jet fan : [image]

See [Full paper containing formulae and diagram](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301804222_EVALUATION_OF_JET_FAN_PERFORMANCE_IN_TUNNELS) for more details.

I believe it may have been originally derived in here > "Truckenbrodt E.:, Fluidmechanik, Band 1: Grundlagen und elementare Strömungsvorgänge dichtebeständiger Fluide (1980)" But i do not have access to this text.

I think it should just be a control volume momentum balance but i can't seem to work it out. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks